# Error en consulta php mysql

Tags: php, html

Tengo un error el cual no he podido solucionar, da los resultados esperados pero al final me saca un error.

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

require('datos.php');

$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_nombre);

if($conexion) {
    if($_POST) {    

        $Cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
        $consulta_existe ="SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cedula='$Cedula'";
        $resultados_existe=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_existe);

        if($resultados_existe==1) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('No existe.'); </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('El cliente ya esta registrado.'); </script>";  
        }

    }
}

?>
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: NO PUEDO VER LA IMAGEN, PUEDES DECIR CUAL ES EL ERROR ?

Comment: `mysqli_query` devuelve un objeto que es un conjunto de resultados. Para poder leerlo tienes que aplicar algún método `fetch`. No puedes obtener los datos directamente de lo que te devuelve `mysqli_query`. No te sugiero una respuesta porque tampoco tu código está claro. Haces un `SELECT *` con un `WHERE` pero no especificas si te interesa una sola fila o todas las filas que cumplan esa condición, tampoco se sabe cuál es la columna que te interesa obtener... Además, tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano tan claro como siempre... me voy a permitir darle una posible respuesta en base a su codigo

Comment: @srJJ claro. Pero convendría quizá indicarle el uso de consultas preparadas explicando el por qué.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo lo que necesitas y las instrucciones del Maestro A. Cedano, te dejo una posible solucion a tu problema utilizando sentencias preparadas para evitar la injeccion de sql:

```
<?php

require('datos.php');

//creamos una instancia
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_nombre);
//verificamos que no hayan errores en la conexion
if(!$mysqli->connect_errno){
  //validamos que los datos llegue y que no esten vacios
  if(isset($_POST['cedula']) && !empty($_POST['cedula']))  {   

    //capturamos la variable del post
    $Cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
    //preparamos la sentencia con el simbolo "?"
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cedula=$Cedula");
    //enviamos el parametro que preparamos 
    $sql->bind_param("i", $Cedula)
    //ejecutamos la sentencia
    $sql->execute();
    //obtenemos el resultado
    $resultado = $sql->get_result();
    //sacamos el numero de filas que trae
    $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    //validamos que si haya traido por lo menos una fila
    if($fila>0) {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('El cliente ya esta registrado.'); </script>";  
    }
    else    {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('No existe.'); </script>";
    }



  }
  else{
    //validamos si no llegaron los datos
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('No llegaron los Datos'); </script>"; 
  }
}
else{
  //mostramos alerta por si fallo la conexion
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Fallo la conexion a la BD'); </script>"; 
 }


?>
```

Espero te sirva y te apoyes en esto aqui te dejo el enlace del [Manual de sentencias Preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) exitos bro. ReNiceCode...